# How to interpret the error message "Foo() takes no arguments" when specifying a class instance as base class?

Tags: python, inheritance, python-internals

The following code:

```py
>>> class Foo: pass
>>> class Spam(Foo()): pass
```

will of course raise an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Foo() takes no arguments
```

But the error info is a little bit odd. Seems that there are some processes when initializing class `Spam`.

I wonder which step causes the error. In other words, why can't class inherit instance, the error message seems to indicate it indeed try something.

---

**Note**: I know there will be no error if write like this `class Spam(Foo)`. But I do it on purpose. I just can't understand the error message, which indicates some procedures exist when class inheriting, I want to know which one procedure causes it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I update my description. Your way can eliminate error, but can't remove my confusion.

Comment: I don't really get what your confusion is - the instantiation of the `Foo` class isn't throwing the exception, it's passing that instance onto the `Spam` class that is.

Comment: @OuterSoda The specific error mentioned however is very confusing. For some reason Python is indeed creating a new instance of the `Foo` class.

Comment: @OuterSoda Yes, but why is the error message "Foo() takes no arguments" and not something like "TypeError: Foo() is not a type usable as base class"

Comment: ah, that's your problem. It's because Foo doesn't have an initialization function (`__init__`) as you just wrote pass. I assumed you would replace it with an actual class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a few dirty print statements we can get the sequence of events that is happening:

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("__init__", self, args, kwargs)

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print("__new__", cls, args, kwargs)
        return super().__new__(cls)

inst = Foo()

class Spam(inst): pass

print(inst, Spam)
```

outputs

```
__new__ <class '__main__.Foo'> () {}
__init__ <__main__.Foo object at 0x0000019FFB399550> () {}
__new__ <class '__main__.Foo'> ('Spam', (<__main__.Foo object at 0x0000019FFB399550>,), {'__module__': '__main__', '__qualname__': 'Spam'}) {}
__init__ <__main__.Foo object at 0x0000019FFB399590> ('Spam', (<__main__.Foo object at 0x0000019FFB399550>,), {'__module__': '__main__', '__qualname__': 'Spam'}) {}
<__main__.Foo object at 0x0000019FFB399550> <__main__.Foo object at 0x0000019FFB399590>
```

So trying to inherit from an instance makes Python create a new instance of that class giving it parameters that would normally go to `type.__new__`.

The reasons this happens is because types in python are objects: When deriving a class, python tries to get the correct meta class by calling `type(base)`, which in this situation returns `Foo` (the class), and then it tries to create an instance of that. ( I could have sworn python checks that `type(base)` is a subclass of `type`, but apparently that is wrong)